# dnf - how to show which mirror url has been chosen?

Tags: fedora, rhel, rpm, repository, dnf

Below is the part of bash log, the full log can be achieved at https://gist.github.com/limkokhole/f2a423112aa005f10862:

```
[xiaobai@xiaobai hello]$ dnf --verbose download --source readline
cachedir: /var/cache/dnf
Loaded plugins: noroot, needs-restarting, reposync, copr, playground, kickstart, Query, generate_completion_cache, builddep, download, config-manager, protected_packages, system-upgrade, debuginfo-install
DNF version: 0.6.4
repo: using cache for: spot-chromium
not found deltainfo for: Copr repo for chromium owned by spot
not found updateinfo for: Copr repo for chromium owned by spot
repo: using cache for: rpmfusion-nonfree-updates-testing
not found deltainfo for: RPM Fusion for Fedora 21 - Nonfree - Test Updates
not found updateinfo for: RPM Fusion for Fedora 21 - Nonfree - Test Updates
repo: using cache for: updates-source
...
not found deltainfo for: RPM Fusion for Fedora 21 - Nonfree - Updates Source
not found updateinfo for: RPM Fusion for Fedora 21 - Nonfree - Updates Source
readline-6.3-5.fc21.src.rpm                                                                                                             623 kB/s | 2.4 MB     00:03    
[xiaobai@xiaobai hello]$
```

I've tried `dnf info` too, the url http://cnswww.cns.cwru.edu/php/chet/readline/rltop.html is not a repo url:

```
[xiaobai@xiaobai hello]$ dnf info readline
[sudo] password for xiaobai: 
Using metadata from Thu Dec 31 19:18:09 2015 (6:13:33 hours old)
Installed Packages
Name        : readline
Arch        : i686
Epoch       : 0
Version     : 6.3
Release     : 5.fc21
Size        : 446 k
Repo        : @System
Summary     : A library for editing typed command lines
URL         : http://cnswww.cns.cwru.edu/php/chet/readline/rltop.html
License     : GPLv3+
Description : The Readline library provides a set of functions that allow users to
            : edit command lines. Both Emacs and vi editing modes are available. The
            : Readline library includes additional functions for maintaining a list
            : of previously-entered command lines for recalling or editing those
            : lines, and for performing csh-like history expansion on previous
            : commands.

Name        : readline
Arch        : x86_64
Epoch       : 0
Version     : 6.3
Release     : 5.fc21
Size        : 483 k
Repo        : @System
Summary     : A library for editing typed command lines
URL         : http://cnswww.cns.cwru.edu/php/chet/readline/rltop.html
License     : GPLv3+
Description : The Readline library provides a set of functions that allow users to
            : edit command lines. Both Emacs and vi editing modes are available. The
            : Readline library includes additional functions for maintaining a list
            : of previously-entered command lines for recalling or editing those
            : lines, and for performing csh-like history expansion on previous
            : commands.

[xiaobai@xiaobai hello]$
```

How can i know which url or domain has been chosen to download this readline-6.3-5.fc21.src.rpm ? `--verbose` doesn't seem to show the link. And how can  i get this url information from dnf history in future after exit the bash session ?

Comment: I don't think it is possible at this point, unless you would be tracking network requests using `wireshark` or `tcpdump`. I might be wrong, but it would not be the firs feature that just does not exist in DNF.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks for @muru to point out the librepo responsible for download.

The current workaround is define a `debug_function` and pass it to `set_debug_log_handler` (refer to [`download_packages.py`](https://github.com/rpm-software-management/librepo/blob/7ba0722dd3caaca2ae6067a5fe58db3edc92e78e/examples/python/download_packages.py)
) in `repo.py`:

```py
def download_payloads(payloads, drpm):
    # download packages
    drpm.err.clear()
    targets = [pload.librepo_target() for pload in payloads]
    errs = _DownloadErrors()
    try:

        #START my custom code
        def debug_function(msg, _):
            print("##hole## msg:", msg)
        librepo.set_debug_log_handler(debug_function)
        #END my custom  code

        librepo.download_packages(targets, failfast=True)
    except librepo.LibrepoException as e:
        errs.fatal = e.args[1] or '<unspecified librepo error>'
    ...
```

This `repo.py` file can be located by manually:

```
[xiaobai@xiaobai log]$ python -c 'import sys, dnf.repo; print(sys.modules["dnf.repo"])'
<module 'dnf.repo' from '/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/dnf/repo.py'>
[xiaobai@xiaobai log]$
```

**[UPDATE]** In Fedora 24, the path is `/usr/lib/python3.5/site-packages/dnf/repo.py`.

And now i'm able to get the url http://ftp.jaist.ac.jp/pub/Linux/Fedora/releases/21/Everything/source/SRPMS/r/readline-6.3-5.fc21.src.rpm:

```
[xiaobai@xiaobai test]$ dnf download --source readline
[sudo] password for xiaobai: 
Using metadata from Thu Dec 31 19:18:09 2015 (1 day, 11:59:10 hours old)
...
##hole## msg: select_next_target: Selecting mirror for: r/readline-6.3-5.fc21.src.rpm
##hole## msg: select_suitable_mirror: Skipping rsync url: rsync://ftp.jaist.ac.jp/pub/Linux/Fedora/releases/21/Everything/source/SRPMS/
##hole## msg: prepare_next_transfer: URL: http://ftp.jaist.ac.jp/pub/Linux/Fedora/releases/21/Everything/source/SRPMS/r/readline-6.3-5.fc21.src.rpm
##hole## msg: prepare_next_transfer: Resume ignored, existing file was not originaly being downloaded by Librepo
##hole## msg: lr_download: Downloading started
##hole## msg: lr_headercb: Server returned Content-Length: "2493152" (converted 2493152/2493152 expected)                             ] ---  B/s |   0  B     --:-- ETA
##hole## msg: check_transfer_statuses: Transfer finished: r/readline-6.3-5.fc21.src.rpm (Effective url: http://ftp.jaist.ac.jp/pub/Linux/Fedora/releases/21/Everything/source/SRPMS/r/readline-6.3-5.fc21.src.rpm)
##hole## msg: check_finished_trasfer_checksum: Checksum (sha256) 521bd47a3293e694190a237921a9954b20fa41d0e8e38183d186452d4cc62ac8 is OK
readline-6.3-5.fc21.src.rpm                                                                                                             1.4 MB/s | 2.4 MB     00:01    
##hole## msg: lr_download_packages: Restoring an old SIGINT handler
[xiaobai@xiaobai test]$
```

Of course, it could be better if dnf log this url for future reference, either retrieve from command `dnf history` or file `/var/log/dnf.log`.

Answer (score 5):

For `dnf` itself, this is [a deferred feature request](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1262845). Apparently `dnf` does not know the URLs. See comments 4 and 5:

> I apologize, I/we have misunderstood the motivation. FYI, DNF actually
>   does not know the URLs. It just knows the URL of the "metalink" and
>   the file name (and some other metadata) of the package. The underlying
>   library librepo is responsible for choosing the best mirror, composing
>   the URL and downloading the file. It means, BTW, that we would need
>   some callback in the library to provide the information to you. Just
>   FYI...
>
> ---
>
> The problem is that we don't know the URL from metalinks, it is taken
>   care on lower level by librepo. If anyone shares the same use case and
>   would like to see this feature, post a comment and you'll get higher
>   chance to have this feature.

Answer (score 2):

```
dnf download readline
cat /var/log/dnf.librepo.log | grep Downloading: | tail -n1
```

And you got there the url from where package is downloaded.

Comment: Are you testing it on Fedora 25 ? I just test it in Fedora 24 but `prepare_next_transfer:` doesn't reflect the latest downloaded `src.rpm`. And i need root to open this log.

Comment: Erm, the correct command should be `sudo download --source readline` in order to get `src.rpm`. It did shows `*.src.rpm` in `/var/log/dnf.log` but it's not a URL. And the correct host did appear in list of urls (`Mirrows from metalink`) in `dnf.librepo.log`, but it doesn't states which host has been chosen. I tested it in Fedora 24.

Comment: `sudo cat /var/log/dnf.librepo.log | grep Effective\ url`

Comment: For current Fedora versions (tested with 39) you'll need `grep Downloading:`. Submitted this also as an edit but not sure if it will get accepted.