# Where can I find the shell script for ls command?

Tags: shell, shell-script, directory-structure

I am trying to understand how the `ls` command works, and I presume there is a shell script which defines `ls` somewhere in the filesystem. This correct? If so, where can I find it?

Comment: it isn't a shell script. Use the 'which' command to find an executable (that exists in the path), e.g. "which ls"

Comment: @nod only use `which` if you're using `tcsh` or have aliased `which` to something like `type -p` or `command -v`.  See http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/85249/why-not-use-which-what-to-use-then

Comment: Did you mean "source code" instead of "shell script" ?

Comment: Perhaps someone once told you, "Everything in Linux is a shell script."  Well, that is a false datum.

Comment: If instead of understanding you wanted to read it... `https://github.com/wertarbyte/coreutils/blob/master/src/ls.c` `:-)`. You may find online the source code. HNY.

Answer (score 7):

`ls` uses `opendir()` and `readdir()` to step through all the files in the directory. If it needs more information about one of them it calls `stat()`. Read the source of course, but a very handy shortcut is :

```
# strace ls
```

The key part with a couple comments is :

> Get the directory entries

```
open(".", O_RDONLY|O_NONBLOCK|O_LARGEFILE|O_DIRECTORY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
fcntl64(3, F_GETFD)                     = 0x1 (flags FD_CLOEXEC)
getdents64(3, /* 53 entries */, 32768)  = 1744
getdents64(3, /* 0 entries */, 32768)   = 0
close(3)                                = 0
```

> Verify stdout is a character device

```
fstat64(1, {st_mode=S_IFCHR|0600, st_rdev=makedev(136, 0), ...}) = 0
```

> map stdin into memory.  (Not sure why, see the source)

```
mmap2(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1,
0) = 0xb73ff000
```

> write the directory entries to stdout and wrap-up

```
write(1, "bin  Desktop  Documents  Downloa"..., 91bin  Desktop
Documents  Download  Music  Pictures  Public  public_html  Templates
Videos
) = 91
close(1)                                = 0
munmap(0xb73ff000, 4096)                = 0
close(2)                                = 0
exit_group(0)                           = ?
```

Answer (score 3):

`ls` is not a shell script, if you issue `file` command, you will know it's an ELF 64-bit LSB executable file:

```
$ type -a ls
ls is aliased to `ls --color=auto'
ls is /usr/bin/ls #<---- now we know the file path of `ls`
ls is /bin/ls
$ 
$ file /usr/bin/ls
/usr/bin/ls: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2, for GNU/Linux 2.6.32, BuildID[sha1]=ddf8cdb3f1fd2e8263637b7c8ccea84fbf41ee3c, stripped
$
```

You can found the online source code [here](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/coreutils.git/tree/src/ls.c).

Or if your distro is RPM-based Linux distributions + `dnf`, then you can:

```
$ rpm -qf /usr/bin/ls
coreutils-8.22-22.fc21.x86_64 #so now we know the package name is coreutils
$ sudo dnf whatprovides /usr/bin/ls #alternative way
Using metadata from Mon May 16 02:39:55 2016 (1 day, 23:03:50 hours old)
coreutils-8.22-22.fc21.x86_64 : A set of basic GNU tools commonly used in shell scripts
Repo        : @System

coreutils-8.22-19.fc21.x86_64 : A set of basic GNU tools commonly used in shell scripts
Repo        : fedora

coreutils-8.22-22.fc21.x86_64 : A set of basic GNU tools commonly used in shell scripts
Repo        : updates

$ 
$ mkdir coreutils #optional
$ cd coreutils #optional
$ sudo dnf download --source coreutils
...
$ rpm2cpio coreutils-8.22-22.fc21.src.rpm |cpio -idmv
...
$ sudo rm coreutils-8.22-22.fc21.src.rpm #optional
$ unp coreutils-8.22.tar.xz
...
$ rm coreutils-8.22.tar.xz #optional
$ cd coreutils-8.22/
$ find . -iname 'ls*'
./lib/lseek.c
./lib/lstat.c
./src/ls.c  #<---- now we know ls.c is here
./src/ls-vdir.c
./src/ls.h
./src/ls-ls.c
./src/ls-dir.c
./man/ls.x
./tests/ls
./tests/misc/ls-misc.pl
./tests/misc/ls-time.sh
./m4/ls-mntd-fs.m4
./m4/lstat.m4
./m4/lseek.m4
$ vi ./src/ls.c
```

Note:

1. coreutils-8.22-22.fc21.src.rpm is mine, your package number may vary.
2. Some commands like `type -a history` return "history is a shell builtin", you should look at the current shell source code, i.e. `` rpm -qf `readlink -f /proc/$$/exe` `` (Detect current shell by command is [tricky](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/37535/64403) than you might think, this trick doesn't work in `fish` shell)
3. In csh/tcsh shell, you should use `where history` because no such `type` command. More details can be found [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/85250/64403).
4. You might also interest to try wildcard, e.g. `repoquery --resolve --archlist=src '*compress*'` to include not installed packages (Be careful if query command like '*uncompress*', in this case you need to remove the prefix 'un' to narrow down if first attempt '*uncompress*' failed). The output from `repoquery` above need to remove middle **0:** and optionally postfix with **.rpm** to get the correct full name which you can used to search in http://rpm.pbone.net , e.g. ncompress-0:4.2.4.4-3.fc21.src change it to ncompress-4.2.4.4-3.fc21.src.rpm
5. You can enable mirror debugging when dnf download source, in case mirror server down. See [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/252774/64403).

**[UPDATE]**

In case you have rpm error due to invalid repos like me, this is how i fixed it:

```
$ sudo dnf config-manager --set-enabled '*' #Enable all repos, at anytime, check with `sudo dnf repolist all`
$ repoquery --resolve --archlist=src '*compress*'                                       
Could not match packages: failure: repodata/repomd.xml from rpmfusion-free-rawhide-source: [Errno 256] No more mirrors to try.
http://free.nchc.org.tw/rpmfusion/free/fedora/development/rawhide/source/SRPMS/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 14] HTTP Error 404 - Not Found                               
...
$ repoquery --resolve --archlist=src --enablerepo='*source' --disablerepo='rpmfusion-free-rawhide-source'  '*compress*' #not works too
...
$ sudo yum-config-manager --save --disablerepo=rpmfusion-nonfree-rawhide-source #for unknown reason, it doesn't work
$ sudo dnf config-manager --set-disabled rpmfusion-free-rawhide-source #for unknown reason, it doesn't work
$ grep -rnIH -D skip --color=always rpmfusion-free-rawhide-source /etc/yum.repos.d/
/etc/yum.repos.d/rpmfusion-free-rawhide.repo:17:[rpmfusion-free-rawhide-source]
$ sudo vi /etc/yum.repos.d/rpmfusion-free-rawhide.repo #Edit rpmfusion-free-rawhide-source from enabled=1 to enabled=0
$ repoquery --resolve --archlist=src  '*compress*'#now should works :) repeat the `grep and vi` steps above if got error in other repos, in my case i have to disable rpmfusion-nonfree-rawhide-source too.
```

**p/s:** Edit the title from [rpmfusion-free-rawhide-source]
 to [rpmfusion-free-rawhide-source**DISABLE**] hack should make
 --enablerepo='*source' works, though so far i found it's unnecessary because i already enable all repos in first command.

Answer (score 1):

I dont know if that is a answer because ls is written in C, but you can write a shell script to do a "ls" using the for loop:

for f in *;do echo $f; done

It is also usefull in some static shells...